# Styled component, eslint with react native gets "no-unused-vars"

Tags: react-native, eslint, styled-components

```
'Text' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Here is the code section gets error

```
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import color from './color';

export const Sub = styled.Text`
  color: ${color.secondary};
  font-size: 16;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 8px;
```

as we can see the `Text` has been consumed by `Sub`, since we don't want remove the `no-unused-vars` rule, we may need a plugin or setting to walk-around this

---

Thanks @Dan, you saved me from my tunnel vision

Comment: `styled.Text` is coming from the `styled-components` package not `react-native`, You can safely remove both imports from `react-native`.

Comment: @Dan Thank you so much, I was blind by `react-native` `StyleSheet` model and could not see the bigger picture

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `Text` is a component, the [documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components) says that the correct way to declare it is:

```js
export const Sub = styled(Text)`
  color: ${color.secondary};
  font-size: 16;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 8px;
`
```

It would also solve the eslint issue.